# Evaluating $f'(1)$ for $f(x) = (x - 1)^{2/3}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Given $f(x) = (x-1)^{2/3}$, find $f'(1)$.

Well, using the derivatives and canceling the terms, I got $(x-1)^{-1/3}$, which is also equal to $1/{(x-1)^{1/3}}$. Plugging 1 into the first one, I got 0, but plugging 1 to the second one, the value does not exist. But there ought to be one answer only. Which one is it, and why then is the other one wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it is not differentiable there!  Consider the same question if someone asked you to find $f'(0)$ for $f(x) = |x|$.

Comment: Also, you lost a constant.

Comment: You shouldn't have gotten zero when you plugged $1$ into $(x-1)^{-1/3}$.

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity, but continuity does not imply differentiability.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are good.  I would add that it really helps to get a graphical/visual understanding of why this might happen.  Here's a graph of your function around $x=1$.

[image: graph of function]

If you start imagining anchoring your secant line at $x=1$ and then closing the gap, you will see the secant lines get steeper and steeper (from either side), so that the tangent line is trying to go vertical.  This manifests itself in the limit of the difference quotient tending toward $\infty$ from the right and $-\infty$ from the left.

At any rate, a vertical line has an undefined (or, I guess "infinite") slope,  and since your slope of tangent is undefined, so is your derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, we have 
$$f'(x)=\frac{2}{3(x-1)^{1/3}}$$
We see that $f'$ is undefined for $x=1$, as the denominator becomes $0$ when $x=1$. So $f'(1)$ is undefined. If you plug in $x=1$ into $(x-1)^{-1/3}$ you should still find that this is undefined, since 
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^{1/3}}=(x-1)^{-1/3}$$
so if the expression on the left is undefined for $x=1$, then the same goes for the expression on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of derivative:
$$f'(1)=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1} \frac{(x-1)^{2/3}-0}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{(x-1)^{1/3}}=\begin{cases}+\infty, \ \ if \ \ x\to 1^+ \\ -\infty, \ \ if \ \  x\to 1^-\end{cases}.$$
It implies that the derivative at $x=1$ does not exist, though the function is continuous at this point.

Comment: Be careful.  While $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{1}{(x - 1)^{1/3}} = \infty$$ $x - 1$ is negative if $x < 1$, so $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{(x - 1)^{1/3}} = -\infty$$  Hence, the limit at $1$ is undefined.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, right, therefore it is $\infty$ without any sign, implying it can be $\pm$ depending on the side of approach. But you are right, no sign may be confused with the positive infinity. Better clarify.

Answer (score 0):

When encountering puzzling behavior of the usual "recipes" for differentiating, it is often helpful to go back to the definition.  That is, we ask ourselves does
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h-1)^{2/3} - (x-1)^{2/3}}{h}\right]
$$
exist, and if so, what is its value.

I'm going to simplify calculations by letting $y=x-1$ since the derivative with respect to $y$ at $y=0$ will be the same as the derivative with respect to $x$ at $x=1$.  Then you can do  the usual trick when evaluating derivatives of powers: For all values of $y$,
$$
(y+h)^{2/3} = y^{2/3} \left(1+ \frac{h}{y}\right)^{2/3} = y^{2/3} \left(1+ \frac23 \frac{h}{y} +O(h^2)\right)\\
(y+h)^{2/3} - (y)^{2/3} = (y)^{2/3}\frac23\frac{h}{y}+O(h^2)= \frac23\frac{h}{y^{1/3}}+O(h^2) \\
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h-1)^{2/3} - (x-1)^{2/3}}{h} = \frac{2}{3y^{1/3}}
$$
which of course becomes undefined as $y\to 0$.

Your confusion setems from treating $(x-1)^{-1/3}$ as $0^k = 0$ without realizing that when $k$ is not positive, $0^k$ is undefined.